# Wrapping text around image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to get text wrap around the image in the page below. Although the image is floated to the left the text doesn't seem to wrap around.

http://goo.gl/SskvJ

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.region` class has a `float:left` rule that should be removed. Then you'd also need to remove the `clear:both` rule on the h2 element. Then you'd want to add a `float:left` rule to the image on the page.

Comment: The solution you suggested works but I am hoping that there is a simpler solution so these changes don't affect the other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. It worked fine with me.

What I've made was creating a div called **content** and I placed inside an ***img*** and also another div that contains text.
Have a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/Apfyv/

Hope it helps!

Comment: That doesn't actually wrap around - add more text and you'll see the text doesn't flow beneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

You have both image and text in a `div` and the are both floated left ... this is fine - but the `div` elements dont have a width specified - so they are taking up 100% (block element) - if you assign the `div`s a width it display to the right of the image

Comment: If I add a width to both the divs then the text would be in a separate column but not wrap around the text

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the text is not wrapping around the image because the text and the graphic are both in two separate DIV tags, you should merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style

```
.region > img {
    float: left;
}
```

And add `display: inline-block` to `#page_product #overview h2`

```
#page_product #overview h2 {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.429;
    display: inline-block;
}
```